# Why doesn't Chabad read Ruth on Shavuot?

Tags: minhag, chabad, shavuos, book-of-ruth

I was at Chabad this Shavuot and they did not read Ruth.  Everywhere else I've been (all Nusach Ashkenaz) has read it claiming that it's appropriate since this is the time of the wheat harvest.

Are there other groups who do not read Ruth on Shavuot?  Are Ashkenazim the only ones who do?  Where did the custom originate?

Also (and maybe this should be a separate question), does Chabad (and other groups who omit Ruth) read Kohelet on Sukkot?

Comment: You could ask too why they omit Akdamus, even though it's in their siddur.

Comment: I've never heard this before. [The Chabad website](http://www.chabad.org/kabbalah/article_cdo/aid/1860031/jewish/Ruth-Shavuot-Connections.htm) says it is "appropriate to read the Book of Ruth" on Shavu'oth.

Comment: Sepharadim dont read Rut or Kohelet publicly the way Ashkenazim do

Comment: @ShmuelBrin thanks, interesting... any insight as to why you don't insert Yetziv Pisgom in the haftorah second day?  Same reason?

Comment: @ShmuelBrin true.

Comment: @yoel I just saw that the Lubavitcher Rebbe says (in the sicha of the second day of Shavuos 5717) that we don't say Akdamus because if someone understands the greatness of Hashem, how lofty he is, and how lofty is the Torah that comes from Him, saying Akdamus may permit one to focus on the "Gilyuim" rather that on Hashem's essence.

Comment: interesting note. Although this isn't the standard chabad minhag the freidiker rebbe would read rus privately on shavuos

Comment: http://www.hakirah.org/Vol23Ron.pdf

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Only Ashkenazic communities read all five *megillos* in a public setting over the course of the year. Sefardic and Chassidic communities generally will only read Eicha on Tisha B'av and (of course) Esther on Purim, but **not** the other three on the *shalosh regalim*.

The custom to read Ruth on Shavuos (as well as Shir Hashirim on Pesach, I think) is mentioned earliest in [Maseches Sofrim (14:18)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=24632&st=&pgnum=40) (although the custom of exactly when during the holiday to say it is not the same). Many reasons are given for each megilla for why it is read on its corresponding holiday, but as far as I know, those are found in more recent works.

Comment: Many sepharadim include the entire Rut in the Tikkun Lel Shavu'ot (as opposed to snippets from the book, as with other sifrei nevi'im and ketuvim).

Comment: @هه: that is the Chabad custom too.

Comment: +1. Re "Chassidic communities generally will only read Eicha... and... Esther", I'm not sure how general that is. Certainly *some* _chasidim_ do read the others. Any idea which _chasiduyos_ do/don't?

Comment: @Alex: The title page of the Chabad Tikkun Leil Shavuot says it is according to the Sheloh.

Comment: @msh210: see [Otzar Minhagei Chabad](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/chasidim/otzar/10/6/19.htm) (last paragraph on the linked page) for a rundown.

Comment: Some sepharadim read Ruth in public before mincha of Yom tov. They use to separate it in two parts for the two days outside Erets Israel. This is the case in France for Jewish from North Africa.

Comment: Jake — actually, like @allced mentioned, many North African and Mediterranean Sephardi communities have the custom of reading Ruth in public on Shavu'ot, separated for the two days — in fact I have a Turkish mahzor which has the reading for Ruth with an interlinear Ladino translation.
For Shir haShirim, most of these communities read it in its entirety every Friday night so reading it on Pesah might seem unnecessary. :)

Answer (score 3):

Chabad does read Rus, just not b’tzibur. It is read in its entirety during Tikun Leil Shavuos when they read through all Tanach per the Arizal's method/instructions.
Chabad only reads b’tzibur the megilos of Esther and Eicha. The other megilos are read on their respective yom tov, b’yachid (but even then not with the tokef of a chiyuv).

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first answer. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 1):

I have a Spanish Portuguese siddur that says to publicly read the first few and last few lines of Ruth after shacharis on weekdays and after mincha on Shabbat starting on Lag B'Omer through ever Shavuot. I don't know if they read the full on Shavuot though.
My understanding was that those Chasidim that don't read Ruth publicly read it privately in the afternoon.

Answer (score -1):

Never heard of such a minhag and according to chabad.org we read ruth on shavuos. http://m.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/2158/jewish/The-Book-of-Ruth.htm

Comment: That only says "in many synagogues it is read publicly." As Alex [said](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16705/why-doesnt-chabad-read-ruth-on-shavuot#comment36221_16706) the part that "The Book of Ruth is recited as part of the program of study for Shavuot night" is the Chabad practice.

Comment: @Yishai Technically, the question never said "public reading at Shacharit".

Comment: @DoubleAA, if the intention of the answer (that it is at least read at some point by everybody), I highly suggest the author clarify that.

Comment: We read it *in spirit*